# compilar en sublimeText 3 codigo python activando una ventana cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, build

talvez mi pregunta no es la más acertada pero bueno para explicar cree un new build system

```
{
"cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "C:/Users/Jsociety/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe", "$file"],
"selector": "source.python",
"shell": true,
"working_dir": "$file_dir"
```

}

todo perfecto consigo que se ejecute los scripts que escribo pero quisiera que cuando presione la tecla enter se cierre la ventana del cmd sin tener que colocar exit() cada rato que ejecute un script quisiera saber si puedo colocar una acción modificando el build que configure para que se comporte así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
se ejecuta todo chevere pero lo que quiero modificar en el build es para dejar de colocar exit() y con tan solo presionar la tecla enter se cierre la ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tal vez sé que es algo molesto por que  argumentarían que podría solo hacer clic en cerrar (X) o escribir exit lo se pero lo pensé y solo quiero saber si hay la posibilidad de hacer eso y de paso aprender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción puede ser la siguiente:

- Usar `shell_cmd` en vez de `cmd` que, aunque no escapa automáticamente argumentos que contienen espacios o entrecomillados, es más flexible.
- Después cambia `cmd /K` por `cmd /C`, la primera ejecuta el comando y después vuelve al *prompt*, mientras que la segunda  ejecuta el comando y termina.
- Por último, puedes concatenar la llamada al intérprete Python con una llamada a `set /p` que bloquee la terminal hasta que <kbd>Enter</kbd> sea pulsado.

El JSON podría ser algo así:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "start cmd /C \"(C:/Users/Jsociety/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe \"$file\" || set /p = Failed execution. Press Enter to exit...) && set /p = Successful execution. Press Enter to exit...\"",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

Comment: me tira esto que significa 
   
  `C:/Users/Jsociety/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe: can't open file 'D:\Proyectos': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Failed execution. Press Enter to exit...`

Comment: @VladimirJoel ¿tiene la ruta de tu script espacios en el nombre de algún directorio o fichero?

Comment: bueno si te refieres a donde eh guardado esto pues lo eh guardado en la siguiente ruta                                                                                                     `C:\Users\Jsociety\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`                pero te juro que yo no cree los directorios  debo de modificar el directorio `Sublime Text 3`??

Comment: No , me refiero a la ruta completa de tu script Python, el que editas y tratas de ejecutar (es decir la ruta que Sublime debe usar para sustituir `$file`). Si no interpreto mal debería estar en "D:\Proyectos..."

Comment: si lo siento habia un espacio en un directorio ya que los scripts se encontraban en                                                                                                   `D:\Proyectos Python\GranCursoPythonUdemy\scripts\seccion1\leccion4`    crees que se deba a eso aun no lo eh probado

Comment: @VladimirJoel si, ese es el problema si no me equivoco. Error mio, debe entrecomillarse la ruta del script para evitar esto (`\"$file\"`). He editado la respuesta, ahora no debe dar problemas. Por favor, prueba cuando puedas a ver si ahora funciona, no tengo ni Windows ni Sublime a mano, aunque no debería haber problemas. Un saludo.

Comment: MI gran amigo quedo excelente